# Kibana: can I store "Time" as a variable and run a consecutive search?

Tags: regex, debugging, elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I want to automate a few search in one, here are the steps:

1. Search in Kibana for this ID:`"b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0"` which will return me a bunch of logs. Of these logs I need to take the first and the last timestamp:

[image]

2. I now would like to store these two data FROM: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:22.155`, TO: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:23.524` in 2 variables
3. Run a second search in Kibana for the word `"fail"` in between these two variable of time

How to **automate** the whole process without need of copy/paste and running a second query?

**EDIT:**

**SHORT STORY LONG:** I work in a company that produce a software for autonomous vehicles. 
**SCENARIO:** A booking is rejected and we need to understand why.
**WHERE IS THE PROBLE:** I need to monitor just a few seconds of logs on 3 different machines. Each log is completely separated, there is no relation between the logs so I cannot write a query in discover, I need to run 3 separated queries.

**EXAMPLE:**

1. A booking was rejected, so I open Chrome and I search on "elk-prod.myhost.com" for the BookingID:`"b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0"` and I have a dozen of logs returned during a range of 2 seconds (FROM: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:22.155`, TO: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:23.524`).
2. Now I need to know what was happening on the car so I open a new Chrome tab and I search on "elk-prod.myhost.com" for the CarID: `"Tesla-45-OU"` on the time range FROM: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:22.155`, TO: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:23.524`
3. Now I need to know why the server which calculate the matching rejected the booking so I open a new Chrome tab and I search for the word `CalculationMatrix` always on the time range FROM: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:22.155`, TO: `September 3rd 2019, 21:28:23.524`

**CONCLUSION:** I want to stop to keep opening Chrome tabs by hand and automate the whole thing. I have no idea around what time the book was made so I first need to search for the BookingID `"b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0"`, then store the timestamp of first and last log and run a second and third query based on those timestamps.

There is no relation between the 3 logs I search so there is no way to filter from the Discover, I need to automate 3 different query.

Comment: I don't thing, you can automate this thing using Kibana. I suppose you need to implement programming interface over Elasticsearch APIs (e.g. python-elasticsearch package for python) to fulfill your requirement and use custom visualization libraries (e.g. D3,js, chart.js etc)

Comment: @AtulK., thank you, do you know if there is a place in Kibana where I can paste my code or should I just run he code on my PC against Kibana? Strange there are no "plugin" for that

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Atul K. Answer is the same as mine, but using another language and he is proposing graphic visualization of data that is optional to solve this issue. As i wrote down in this solution you do not use Kibana at all. You use Elasticsearch as a database. In Kibana you can run many queries, but not paste some for example `Python` code.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I'm new to Kibana. I will wait some week and see what I can do and maybe edit the question again and add more bounty. I still believe is a problem that many person face

Comment: Hi Francesco! Just to clarify something from our discussion last evening: the second search is run on a different index, correct?

Comment: Hi @Val, I updated my post. Just reply "possible" or "not possible", at least I will sleep tonight. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. First of all, from what I understand, you have three different indexes:

- one for "bookings"
- one for "cars"
- one for "matchings"

First, in Discover, I would create three Saved Searches, one per index pattern. Then in Visualize, I would create a Vertical bar chart on the bookings saved search (Bucket X-Axis by `date_histogram` on the `timestamp` field, leave the rest as is). You'll get a nice histogram of all your booking events bucketed by time.
Finally, I would create a dashboard and add the vertical bar chart + those three saved searches inside it.

When done, the way I would search according to the process you've described above is as follows:

1. Search for the booking ID `b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0` in the top filter bar. In the bar chart histogram (bookings), you will see all documents related to the selected booking. On that chart, you can select the exact period from when the very first booking document happened to the very last. This will adapt the main time picker at the top and the start/end time will be "remembered" by Kibana
2. Remove the booking ID from the top filter (since we now know the time range and Kibana stores it). Search for `Tesla-45-OU` in the top filter bar. The bar histogram + the booking saved search + the matchings saved search will be empty, but you'll have data inside the second list, the one for cars. Find whatever you need to find in there and go to the next step.
3. Remove the car ID from the top filter and search for `ComputationMatrix`. Now the third saved search is going to show you whatever documents you need to see within that time range.

I'm lacking realistic data to try this out, but I definitely think this is possible as I've laid out above, probably with some adaptations.

Comment: Thank you @Val, I will give it a try and I will eventually give you a feedback in the next months or so

Comment: Sure thing Francesco, let me know

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Well the edited version is very different from where you first posted here `How to automate the whole process without need of copy/paste and running a second query?` and search for word `fail` in a single shot. Here you are still using a three filters one at a time so it is not one search, but `three`.
What's more if you would use one index, and send data from multiple hosts via `filebeat` you don't even to have to create this `dashboard` to do that. Then you can `you can select the exact period from when the very first document happened to the very last` regarding filter.

Comment: @yami as Francesco explained, the three different documents have close to no fields in common, so storing them in the same index is not advised at all.

Comment: I agree, but you  don't have to create `dashboard` even if you are using different indicies. You change them easily in `dicover` see: https://imgur.com/a/HAX0gAb
So you can go `discover` select `indice 1` search, select time range that you need, when you change `indicie` the `time range` is still the one you selected, you only need to change filter - you will get what you need.

Comment: The dashboard aggregates three discover views, hence you don't need to change anything, that's the whole point

Comment: As i understood your post you are changing filters in the `dashboard`. But the gain is that you don't have to change `indicies`.

Comment: He has three different filters (one for each index). The only thing that remains unchanged is the time picker. So instead of changing the index pattern and the filter in the discover view three times, it's probably easier to only have to change the filter in an aggregated dashboard view, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, sure it is gain that you don't need to change index as i wrote before and I agree with that. I meant that you don't need it to achieve Francesco goal and i wanted him to show another way.

Comment: It's the same way, just aggregated into a dashboard ;-) And after speaking with Francesco, he wants to do as few manipulations as possible as he's carried out that process all day long.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana does work like this (any order is ok):

1. Select time filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/set-time-filter.html
2. Add additional criteria for search like for example field `s` is `b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0`.
3. Add aditional criteria for search like for example field `x` is `Fail`.

Additionaly you can `view surrounding documents` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/document-context.html#document-context

This is how `Kibana` works.

You can prepare some `filters` beforehands, save them and then use them if you want to `automate` the process of discovering somehow.
You can do that in `Discover` tab in `Kibana` using `New/Save/Open` options.

**Edit:**
I do not think you can achieve what you need in Kibana. As I mentioned earlier one option is to change the data that is comming to Elasticsearch so you can search for it via discover in Kibana. Another option could be builiding for example Java application, that is using Elasticsearch - then you can write algorithm that returns the data that you want. But i think it's a big overhead and I recommend checking the data first.

**Edit**: To clarify - you can create external `Java` let's say `SpringBoot` application that uses `Elasticsearch` - all the data that you need is inside it.
But in this option you will not use `Kibana` at all.
You can export the result to `csv` or what you want in the code.
`SpringBoot` application can ask `ElasticSearch` for whatever it needs, then it would be easy to store these time variables inside of `Java` code.

**EDIT: After OP edited question to change it dramatically:**

@FrancescoMantovani Well the edited version is very different from where you first posted here `How to automate the whole process without need of copy/paste and running a second query?` and search for word `fail` in a single shot. In accepted answer you are still using a three filters one at a time so it is not one search, but three.
What's more if you would use one index, and send data from multiple hosts via `filebeat` you don't even to have to create this `dashboard` to do that. Then you can `you can select the exact period from when the very first document happened to the very last` regarding filter and then remove it and add another filter that you need - it's simple as that. Before you were writing about `one query`,

> How to automate the whole process **without need of** copy/paste and
>   **running a second query**?

not `three`. And you don't need to open new tab in `Chrome` each time you want to change filter just organize the data by for example using `filebeat` as mentioned before.

> There is no relation between the 3 logs

From what you wrote the realation exist and it is **time**.

If the data is in for example `three diferent indicies` (cause documents don't have much similiar data) you can do it like that:

You change them easily in `dicover` see: 
[image]
You can go to `discover` select `index 1` search, select time range that you need, when you change `index` the `time range` is still the one you selected, you only need to change filter - you will get what you need.

Comment: Thank you but not. I cannot search in Kbana `b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0` AND `fail` because they are not in the same log. I need to 1) search for b2c729b5-6440-4829-8562-abd81991e2a0, 2) store the time of the first and last log in 2 separate variables, 3) run a second query in Kibana using `fail` and targeting the gap of time of the 2 variables

Comment: They do not have to be in the same log. Kibana can aggregate many logs via for example `Filebeat` and you can use for example `OR` operator in search. What you can do is search for this `id` and then use `view surrounding documents` option  with filters that you need - you don't have to store these time variables.

Comment: I know I can use `view surrounding documents` but the problem is that I have to do this 30-50 times per day and when we will have more customers you have to multiply this exponentially. I want automation, this is what computers are made for, right? I cannot believe no one at Elasticsearch has ever faced this problem

Comment: The issue is that you want very specific job to done and you could make the right data to achieve your goal in Kibana to do it in less searches. I would need more informations to assist you where is the main issue here. Maybe you need to use some aggregation or `logstash` data manipulation.
By default you should be able to search your issue in `Discover` tab without `viewing surrounding documents`.

Comment: I like the Java application option, this is what I was looking for. Can you be more consistent and tell me where to paste the code? If Kibana has a special place where to paste the code snippet?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify what i mean by `Java` application and where is `Kibana` in this solution.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I edited the answer cause you changed the question dramatically.

Comment: You are right @yami, definitely the time is the relation between those logs. But the only way to find the time is to run the first query. Then store the time somewhere in a variable and in behalf of that time run the other 2 queries. I still cannot believe I'm the only one facing this problem. I will give it a go and I will let you know. Do you think I can archive that through the Dev Tools? https://snipboard.io/nJxw8Q.jpg

Comment: I know `devtools` but i don't think it is possible to store time as variable there cause of that i did not reccomend it.